# Highlighting cell on specific time in jQuery by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How can I highlight a cell (each `td` is described by unique `class`) on specific time in jQuery? For instance:

```
 <tr class="first">
    <td class="datetime">08:20<br>9.50</td>
    <td class="111"></td>
    <td class="112"></td>
    <td class="113"></td>
    <td class="114"></td>
    <td class="115"></td>
    <td class="116"></td>
</tr>
```

I need to highlight `111` each Monday between `8:20` and `9.50`.

How can I do this ?

Comment: when you say each monday do you mean there are multiple elements on the page that contain `111` and you want to just target the monday ones? or is `111` unique to mondays?

Comment: i think you are lookin for javascript date object

Comment: is this relative to the current user's timezone? or based on a specific location in the world?

Comment: Assuming that you can use the user's local time, you can use the Date() object to determine current Week day and Time. Once you have the classname you want to highlight, just apply a new class or something `$(".111").addClass("highlight")`

Comment: Please make your question a little clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that will take the current users time and check it against your requirements

```
var currentUNIX = new Date().getTime(); // get user's current UNIX timecode
var currentDay = new Date(currentUNIX).getDay(); // 0: Sunday -> 6:Saturday
var currentHour = new Date(currentUNIX).getHours(); // in 24 hours time
var currentMinute = new Date(currentUNIX).getMinutes();

if(currentDay == 1){ // if Monday
    if(
        (currentHour >= 8 && currentMinute >= 20) && // if later than 8:19
        (currentHour <= 9 && currentMinute <= 50) // and earlier than 9:51
    ){
       $('.111').addClass('highlight');
    }
}
```

For more information about the JS `Date` object have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (it also includes a full list of the methods available for it)